# ArcGIS - Can't create shapefile showing footprint of raster extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, extents

I'm trying to create a shapefile with the extent of my raster so that it can be used as a mask to clip with. My shapefile has no datapixels along its boundary and is irregularly shaped.

So far I've put my raster into a mosaic dataset to create a footprint shapefile. However, on closer inspection this footprint shapefile cuts across valid pixels in my irregularly shaped raster image.

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of raster to polygon conversion in ArcGIS is to simplify the output polygon geometry, which I guess is the reason why your extent is not exactly the same as the pixel that you have as input (see illustration from ArcGIS help below)

[image]

The solution is thus to uncheck "simplify polygon" hen you run the conversion tool. '''arcpy.conversion.RasterToPolygon(in_raster, out_polygon_features, "NO_SIMPLIFY")'''

Rem: I assume that your raster is reclassified before the conversion in order to have a single value for all valid pixels before the conversion.